# How to adjust the content and table when it overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my webpage I have on slide-out side bar, when it slide out it shifted the other contents and make overflow and add scrobble bar. 
I don't want overflow and content remain inside window and adjust according to remaining space.

**Image Slide-out side bar**

[image]
Here we can see that content is inside window, no overflow. But When we press the slide-out side bar it make overflow the remaining content. Plz see the following image. Content goes outside windows.
**I want to adjust the content according to window but not overflow. Similarly if there is table then it adjust according to window but no overflow.**

[image]

Css+html+javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Making it swipeable - Swipeable Side Menu</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>


    <style type="text/css">
      body, html {
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0;
          overflow:hidden;
          font-family: helvetica;
          font-weight: 100;
      }
      .container {
          position: relative;
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          left: 0;
          -webkit-transition:  left 0.4s ease-in-out;
          -moz-transition:  left 0.4s ease-in-out;
          -ms-transition:  left 0.4s ease-in-out;
          -o-transition:  left 0.4s ease-in-out;
          transition:  left 0.4s ease-in-out;
      }
      .container.open-sidebar {
          left: 240px;
      }

      .swipe-area {
          position: absolute;
          width: 50px;
          left: 0;
      top: 0;
          height: 100%;
          background: #f3f3f3;
          z-index: 0;
      }
      #sidebar {
          background: #DF314D;
          position: absolute;
          width: 240px;
          height: 100%;
          left: -240px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      #sidebar ul {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          list-style: none;
      }
      #sidebar ul li {
          margin: 0;
      }
      #sidebar ul li a {
          padding: 15px 20px;
          font-size: 16px;
          font-weight: 100;
          color: white;
          text-decoration: none;
          display: block;
          border-bottom: 1px solid #C9223D;
          -webkit-transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
          -moz-transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
          -ms-transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
          -o-transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
          transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
      }
      #sidebar ul li:hover a {
          background: #C9223D;
      }
      .main-content {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          padding: 10px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          position: relative;
      }
      .main-content .content{
          box-sizing: border-box;
          -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      padding-left: 60px;
      width: 100%;
      }
      .main-content .content h1{
          font-weight: 100;
      }
      .main-content .content p{
          width: 100%;
          line-height: 160%;
      }
      .main-content #sidebar-toggle {
          background: #DF314D;
          border-radius: 3px;
          display: block;
          position: relative;
          padding: 10px 7px;
          float: left;
      }
      .main-content #sidebar-toggle .bar{
           display: block;
          width: 18px;
          margin-bottom: 3px;
          height: 2px;
          background-color: #fff;
          border-radius: 1px;   
      }
      .main-content #sidebar-toggle .bar:last-child{
           margin-bottom: 0;   
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(window).load(function(){
        $("[data-toggle]").click(function() {
          var toggle_el = $(this).data("toggle");
          $(toggle_el).toggleClass("open-sidebar");
        });
         $(".swipe-area").swipe({
              swipeStatus:function(event, phase, direction, distance, duration, fingers)
                  {
                      if (phase=="move" && direction =="right") {
                           $(".container").addClass("open-sidebar");
                           return false;
                      }
                      if (phase=="move" && direction =="left") {
                           $(".container").removeClass("open-sidebar");
                           return false;
                      }
                  }
          }); 
      });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="sidebar">
          <ul>
              <li><a href="demo3.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="demo3.html">Explore</a></li>
              <li><a href="demo3.html">Users</a></li>
              <li><a href="demo3.html">Sign Out</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="main-content">
          <div class="swipe-area"></div>
          <a href="#" data-toggle=".container" id="sidebar-toggle">
              <span class="bar"></span>
              <span class="bar"></span>
              <span class="bar"></span>
          </a>
          <div class="content">
              <h1>Creating Swipeable Side Menu For the Web</h1>
              <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is the `overflow: hidden;` ind your `body` necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***JS***

```
$(window).load(function(){
        $("[data-toggle]").click(function() {
          var toggle_el = $(this).data("toggle");
          $(toggle_el).toggleClass("open-sidebar");
                 if($(toggle_el).hasClass("open-sidebar")){
                     console.log($('.content').width()); 
                   console.log(parseInt($('.content').width())-240);
            $('.content').width(parseInt($('.content').width())-240);
          }
          else
            $(".content").css('width','100%');
        });
         $(".swipe-area").swipe({
              swipeStatus:function(event, phase, direction, distance, duration, fingers)
                  {
                      if (phase=="move" && direction =="right") {
                           $(".container").addClass("open-sidebar");
                           return false;
                      }
                      if (phase=="move" && direction =="left") {
                           $(".container").removeClass("open-sidebar");
                           return false;
                      }
                  }
          }); 
      });
```

Since you dont want overflow property to be changed lets achive this with the help of JQuery API

```
if($(toggle_el).hasClass("open-sidebar")){
                         console.log($('.content').width()); 
                       console.log(parseInt($('.content').width())-240);
                $('.content').width(parseInt($('.content').width())-240);
              }
              else
                $(".content").css('width','100%');
```

The above dynamically calculates the width and adjust your content Accordingly I have adjuested the content of the screnn if your want you can adject the whole screen or the complete container which has it

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwWRYV)

Comment: @neelabhsingh are you stating that instead of the div you might use table for the .content div

Answer (score 1):

You can do it modifying a couple of CSS.

First, replace `left` property by `padding-left` in `.container.open-sidebar` and do the same for the transitions in `.container`:

```
.container {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      left: 0;
      box-sizing:border-box;
      -webkit-transition:  padding-left 0.4s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition:  padding-left 0.4s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition:  padding-left 0.4s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition:  padding-left 0.4s ease-in-out;
      transition:  padding-left 0.4s ease-in-out;
  }
  .container.open-sidebar {
      padding-left: 240px;
  }
```

Create a new css rule just below `#sidebar`:

```
.container.open-sidebar #sidebar {
      left: 0px;
}
```

Then, add transition in `#sidebar` :

```
#sidebar {
      background: #DF314D;
      position: absolute;
      width: 240px;
      height: 100%;
      left: -240px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      -webkit-transition:  left 0.4s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition:  left 0.4s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition:  left 0.4s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition:  left 0.4s ease-in-out;
      transition:  left 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

Finally, add `box-sizing` in `.container`  :

```
.container {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      left: 0;
      box-sizing:border-box;
      -webkit-transition:  left 0.4s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition:  left 0.4s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition:  left 0.4s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition:  left 0.4s ease-in-out;
      transition:  left 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

> [Live exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/8na71uq6/)

---

Clicking the button, the entire container was swiping to the right. That you didn't want. So here, we are replacing the `left` property translation with a `padding-left` in order to leave an empty area for the sidebar. And we then apply the `left` transition to the sidebar only. `box-sizing`property is used to tell the container that the `width:100%` must consider the `padding-left`.